# SkiaSharp save image with ICC profile

Tags: c#, .net-core, skiasharp

In SkiaSharp, when you create a new image from an existing image (e.g. such as when resizing), how can you save the new image with the ICC profile from the original image?

Answer (score 5):

So the answer is: Skia will automatically apply the ICC profile **if the `ColorSpace` is set and maintained between both the source image and the destination image**.

**The `ColorSpace` must be set on the source object AND the destination object (SKBitmap, SKImage, SKSurface, etc).** This is so Skia can know how to convert the colors between the source and destination. If the `ColorSpace` is not set on either of those, or if either `ColorSpace` gets lost along the way (which easily happens when you're creating new objects), Skia will use default settings which can skew the color conversion.

#### Example of the correct way to maintain ColorSpace:

```
using (SKData origData = SKData.Create(imgStream)) // convert the stream into SKData
using (SKImage srcImg = SKImage.FromEncodedData(origData))
    // srcImg now contains the original ColorSpace (e.g. CMYK)
{
    SKImageInfo info = new SKImageInfo(resizeWidth, resizeHeight,
        SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul, SKColorSpace.CreateSrgb());
    // this is the important part. set the destination ColorSpace as
    // `SKColorSpace.CreateSrgb()`. Skia will then be able to automatically convert
    // the original CMYK colorspace, to this new sRGB colorspace.

    using (SKImage newImg = SKImage.Create(info)) // new image. ColorSpace set via `info`
    {
        srcImg.ScalePixels(newImg.PeekPixels(), SKFilterQuality.None);
        // now when doing this resize, Skia knows the original ColorSpace, and the
        // destination ColorSpace, and converts the colors from CMYK to sRGB.
    }
}
```

#### Another example to maintain ColorSpace:

```
using (SKCodec codec = SKCodec.Create(imgStream)) // create a codec with the imgStream
{
    SKImageInfo info = new SKImageInfo(codec.Info.Width, codec.Info.Height,
        SKImageInfo.PlatformColorType, SKAlphaType.Premul, SKColorSpace.CreateSrgb());
    // set the destination ColorSpace via SKColorSpace.CreateSrgb()

    SKBitmap srcImg = SKBitmap.Decode(codec, info);
    // Skia creates a new bitmap, converting the codec ColorSpace (e.g. CMYK) to the
    // destination ColorSpace (sRGB)
}
```

Additional, very helpful information about Skia color correction: https://skia.org/user/sample/color?cl=9919